# Python/Dash: convert a callback a variable from a integer/float to a list-Type?

Tags: callback, rangeslider

Hello and many Thanks in advance for help!
I want to give a RangeSlider a value over a dcc.store variable.
Could it be, that a Variable that I create in a dcc.Store (ProzessgraphMin) is changed to a list when I used it in a callback?
Because I got a Error that the variable min_Slider is a list and not a float/int/String that means that the RangeSlider don't take the value of the variable.

*"Invalid argument "min" passed into RangeSlider with ID ""rangeSlider_P
Failed component prop type: Invalid component prop 'max' of type 'array' supplied to function..... Was supplied type 'array'
Value provided:[166.129]"*

But I don't know why the variable should be a list....
Can anyone help?

### dcc.Store(id="ProzessgraphMin", data=50.10, storage_type='memory'),

### @app.callback(
State('ProzessgraphMin', 'data'),

### def store_current_data3(Auswahl_Toleranz_value, ProzessgraphMin_data,

```
min_Slider_P=ProzessgraphMin_data
print('ProzessgraphMin_data Typ: ',type(ProzessgraphMin_data))
```

---

I tried to change the variable in the store from a list to a single element for example I started with prozessgraph data =[50,500].